# Is the convolution of the Heaviside distribution with itself well defined?

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, convolution, dirac-delta

During a lecture, we were told that for two distributions $S,T \in \mathcal{D'}(\mathbb{R})$ the convolution $S* T$ is defined if either $S$ or $T$ had a compact support, or, if both of them were tempered distributions.

With that said, the Heaviside distribution does not appear to have a compact support, nor is it a tempered distribution. Meaning that $H * H$, where $H$ denotes the Heaviside functional, is not well defined.

Yet, our professor asked us to prove that the second derivative of $H * H$ is equal to Dirac's delta.
$$
(H * H)'' = \delta_0
$$
How is this possible?

Comment: More generally, the convolution of $S,T\in \mathcal D^\prime(\mathbb R)$ can be defined if for every $R>0$ the set $\{(x,y)\in \mathrm{supp}(S)\times\mathrm{supp}(T)\mid \lvert x+y\rvert\leq R\}$ is bounded. I know this as "strip condition", but I couldn't find any references after a quick web search. Maybe someone else is more successful.

Comment: The convolution product of two "causal" distributions (i.e., with support included in $\mathbb{R}^+$) is always well defined.

Comment: Not "casual" but "causal" (very usual term in Laplace transform) : the definition is in the parentheses of my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly $H$ is locally integrable.  It constitutes, therefore, a Tempered Distribution and for any $\phi\in C_C^\infty$, we have

$$\langle H,\phi\rangle =\int_0^\infty \phi(x)\,dx$$

---

The convolution $H*H$ is also a distribution such that for any $\phi\in C_C^\infty$ we have

$$\begin{align}
\langle H*H,\phi\rangle &= \langle H, H*(d_{-1} \phi)\rangle\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty H(x) \int_{-\infty}^\infty H(y)\phi(x+y)\,dy\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \phi(x+y)\,dy\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty \int_x^\infty \phi(y)\,dy\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty \phi(y)\int_0^y\,dx\,dy\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty y\phi(y)\,dy\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty yH(y)\phi(y)\,dy\tag1
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we see from $(1)$ that in distribution

$$(H*H)(x)=xH(x)\tag2$$.

---

Finally, using $(2)$ we see that the second distributional derivative $(H*H)''$ of $H*H$ satisfies

$$\begin{align}
\langle (H*H)'', \phi\rangle&=\langle H*H, \phi''\rangle\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty xH(x) \phi''(x)\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty x\phi''(x)\,dx\\\\
&=\phi(0)
\end{align}$$

so that in distribution we have

$$(H*H)''(x)=\delta(x)$$

as was to be shown!

---

Note that we could have derived $(2)$ directly by writing

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty H(x')H(x-x')\,dx'&=\int_0^{xH(x)} \,dx'\\\\
&=xH(x)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Although I am not sure why $H$ being locally integrable implies that it is tempered, since it needs to be linear and continuous on the set of Schwartz functions to be tempered.

Comment: All locally intergrable function are indeed tempered distributions.